# Не проходит авторизаци vk api python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, python-3.5

Добрый день! Пытаюсь постить через `vk api` в группу, в среде работает нормально, а когда заливаю на сервер, требует подтвердить номер телtфона, что-то не могу сообразить как его передать `vk`

вот ошибка:

```
-raise SecurityCheck(phone_prefix, phone_postfix)
vk_api.exceptions.SecurityCheck: Security check. Enter number: 7 ...24
```

вот код:

```
import vk_api
import sys
import random

def vk_auth(login, passwordl):
    vk = vk_api.VkApi(login, password)

    try:
        vk.auth()  # Авторизируемся
    except vk_api.AuthError as error_msg:
        print(error_msg)  # В случае ошибки выведем сообщение
        sys.exit()

    return vk
login = ''
password = ''
OWNER_ID = '-'

vk=vk_auth(login, password)

rs = vk.method('wall.post', {
          'owner_id': OWNER_ID,
          'message': '1',
          'from_group':1
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вк считает, что Вы заходите из подозрительного места, т.к. у вас поменялся ип, я особо не заморачивался с подтверждением телефона через код, просто пробросил порт на сервер и поставил прокси в браузере:

```
 ssh -fND 127.0.0.1:7777 name@my.serv.ip.addr
```

Например:

```
 ssh -fND 127.0.0.1:7777 admin@8.8.8.8
```

Теперь читаем как подключить прокси в вашем браузере, заходим [сюда](http://api.sypexgeo.net/json), если адрес ип изменился на адрес сервера, мы все сделали верно, идем в вк, подтверждаем номер, запускаем скрипт на сервере.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!

Comment: @egorkh Пожалуйста:)